# How to select a treeview node from code in eclipse-plugin

Tags: java, swt, jface

I have a custom outline in my Eclipse plug-in, implemented using class `TreeViewer` and I created this outline using this code:

```
public class MyOutlinePage extends ContentOutlinePage
(...)
            Object[] data = (...)
            TreeViewer treeViewer = getTreeViewer();
            treeViewer.setInput(data);
```

And after set input I need to select one specific element in outline.
For example, I need to select the element `data[2]` in the outline.
It must be the same that I click in the element using mouse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tree viewer has a `setSelection` method to programmatically change its selection. If you *wrap* you domain object into a `StructuredSeletion` the corresponding `TreeItem` will be selected.

```
treeViewer.setSelection( new StructuredSelection( data[2] ) );
```

Comment: When I select an item of outline using mouse, the property view is updated, and the item selected is like that image: http://oi57.tinypic.com/68c58i.jpg .

But when I select using treeViewer.setSelection, the property view is NOT updated and imagem is like that: http://oi60.tinypic.com/2r5gfo5.jpg .

The listenner of treeViewer adding by addSelectionChangedListener was executed, but I need to simulate mouse click to update the property view.

Comment: In order for the property view to update, the `TreeViewer` of the outline view must be set as a selection provider before calling `setSelection()`. Can you ensure that this is the case?

Comment: I created another post because its post help me to select item but now I have another problem, the selection doen not update the properties view.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29214920/how-to-select-a-treeview-node-like-a-click-of-mouse-to-update-properties-view