# How to select a treeview node like a click of mouse to update properties view

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, swt, jface

I have a custom outline in my Eclipse plug-in, implemented using class `TreeViewer` and I created this outline using this code:

```
public class MyOutlinePage extends ContentOutlinePage
(...)
            Object[] data = (...)
            TreeViewer treeViewer = getTreeViewer();
            treeViewer.setInput(data);
```

After set input I need to select one specific element in outline.
For example, I need to select the element `data[2]` in the outline.

Im trying to use this code to select the emelent of outline:

```
treeViewer.setSelection(new StructuredSelection(data[2]));
```

If I select the outline item using mouse, the outline was selected and the "Properties Views" was updated. The outline item is selected as shown:

[image]

But If I select the outline item using the method `setSelection` the "Properties Views" was NOT updated and the outline item is selected as shown:

[image]

I need to select outline item using code and this selection must update the "Properties View" like the click of mouse does.

Comment: Does the `TreeViewer` have the focus? I.e. is it the focus control?

Comment: The gray highlight shows that the outline view is not the active part. The Properties view always shows values from the active part.

Comment: When I select the outline item using code, the outline has not focus. The focus is on the document or properties view. I need to select outline item and active it... but how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The gray highlight shows that the outline view is not the active part. The Properties view always shows values from the active part.

You can activate the Outline view with:

```
IWorkbenchPage page = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getActivePage();

page.showView(IPageLayout.ID_OUTLINE, null, IWorkbenchPage.VIEW_ACTIVATE);
```

but note that this will move focus away from whatever part is currently active.